# Pass a function call to child shell

Tags: bash, shell, ksh

My ksh `main_script` has a call to another script `called_script`. The `called_script` ends up creating a child shell which I want to continue working in. I pass it a function `fun` that needs to be executed.

```
called_script <<< '
fun
'
```

I get an error saying `fun: not found [No such file or directory]`, but when I run the `called_script` followed by `fun` manually (i.e. directly without using `main_script`) it works. It seems to me that the `called_script` execution defines the function. In that case why does using `main_script` end up with different result?

Note: I cannot change `called_script`.

EDIT: I believe the `called_script` spawns a shell and calls other scripts which define `fun`. I need the `called_script` finish it's stuff completely before running what I passed in the here string in `main_script`. Is there any way to control the order.

Comment: The `called_script` ends up creating a child shell which I want to continue working in -- show how the child shell is created. Generally, to do what you want it's simply `exec 'cmd_that_creates_child_shell'`

Comment: Does some setup and calls `ENV=/home/me/bin/.kshrc ksh` at the end. @DavidC.Rankin

Comment: Please provide a [mre] complete enough that one could reasonably expect it to be runnable if your problem were solved without needing to add additional components.

Comment: I cannot publish the actual code. I will try to cook up some dummy example that replicates the behavior.

Comment: You will have to cook up some minimal example. I understand, whether it is school or for business, that you cannot provide the actual script, but a dummy that shows how you handle the *here-string* and what you need to execute at the end is needed. Without more, the original comment would likely become, place `exec /thing/you/run/at/end` to have that replace and become the current shell that is executing.